# github - permission error

Tags: github, github-for-mac

On our linode server, we have git installed.  We can pull our development branch but not the master.  We get the error below when we try and use the following command:

Command:

```
git remote set-url origin https://myusername@github.com/projectname/Projectname.com.git
```

Error:

```
error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
```

We're under pressure to launch our laravel site and cannot seem to get any further.

Comment: What are the permissions/ownership on that file and parent directory?

Comment: It does look very much like it isn't writable but struggling to see how we change permissions.  Can you give any pointers?